# iOS Nest Firebase Framework [nest-api]

Tags: nest-api

I am currently using Firbase 1.2.3 provided with the Nest SDK for iOS. I have found that the Firebase Framework provided is so dated it cannot built with Bitcode enabled. This means I cannot build the whole project with Bitcode support. It appears from the documentation they are still pushing Firebase, however in practice they are not updating it. For example, I believe Firebase is currently up to version 2.3.4 (Bitcode Supported). When I use the later version the authorization process is unstable and can take a long time. Has anyone been successful and using a more recent Firebase Framework?

Comment: ya unfortunately this is currently the case. What is your use case? Perhaps typical REST or Rest Streaming can fit what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks. I probably could, however I didn't want to spend the time into making the changes as it appears the Nest development is not very active. I'm afraid it will become obselete. I do appreciate your suggestion.